# new Date("") adding GMT hours

Tags: javascript, date

```
var start = new Date("2017-04-09T21:00:00");
```

output: Mon Apr 10 2017 05:00:00 GMT+0800 (+08)

it suppose to be: Sun Apr 09 2017 21:00:00 GMT+0800 (+08)

Comment: Remote `T` from `"2017-04-09T21:00:00"`

Comment: But I am using FullCalendar than it it working fine while putting dates with `T`.

Comment: What about start.toUTCString(); ?

Comment: @Smit what text is passed from `FullCalendar` to `Date` constructor

Comment: @gurvinder372—that will make it not an ISO 8601 string and then parsing will be implementation dependent. Safari will return an invalid date.

Comment: @gurvinder372 it in a [moment](https://momentjs.com) form.

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy. you can try this:

```js
var start = new Date("2017-04-09T21:00:00");
start.setTime(start.getTime() + start.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000);

console.log(start);
```

Comment: Except that `new Date("2017-04-09T21:00:00")` returns different results in different browsers. For me, in Firefox 49, the above returns "2017-04-09T01:00:00.000Z". In Safari it returns "2017-04-09T11:00:00.000Z". According to ECMA-262 it should be treated as local, so adjustment for the local timezone should not be required.

Comment: In firefox, when you pass parameter to Date() constructor it treated as local time and return the greenwich mean time. But, in chrome the parameter is treated as greenwich mean time and return the local time. So, you need to detect the browser and according to this calculate the time (output). But I didn't understand why Safari return the unexpected result.

Comment: If you head down the path of browser sniffing you're in a world of pain. Just parse the string manually.

Answer (score 1):

There is a golden rule that you should never parse strings with the Date constructor (or Date.parse, they are equivalent for parsing).

According to [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format), an ISO 8601 format date without a timezone should be treated as local:

> When the time zone offset is absent, date-only forms are interpreted
>   as a UTC time and date-time forms are interpreted as a local time.

So `new Date("2017-04-09T21:00:00")` should return a date for 9 April 2017 at 9:00 pm in the host timezone.

However, testing in Safari 10 and Chrome 57 shows that "2017-04-09T21:00:00" is treated as Z or GMT+0000. Firefox 49 bizarrely seems to treat it as UTC then adjusts for the local timezone the wrong way. However, Firefox 38 correctly treats it as local.

So **always** manually parse strings. Use a library or write a short function, e.g.

```js
// Parse 2017-04-09T11:00:00.000 as local
function parseISOLocal(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[0], b[1]-1, b[2], (b[3]||0),
                 (b[4]||0), (b[5]||0), (b[6]||0));
}

var s = '2017-04-09T21:00:00.000';
console.log('Built-in parser: ' + new Date(s).toString());
console.log('parseISOLocal  : ' + parseISOLocal(s).toString());
```